# VueJS - filter items from checkbox selection

Tags: arrays, checkbox, vue.js, vuejs2

I am looking to refine my data output by the category names.

How to filter the output items by the **cat_array**? Whilst preserving my text search filter?

```
    {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Title one",
    "category_data": {
        "2": "Team",
        "7": "Queries"
    }
},
```

I had tested using this:

```
return  vm.info.filter(item => this.cat_array.includes(item.category_id))
```

**Codepen example**: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XxNORW?editors=1011

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach - (*Didn't take care of the `All` logic*):

```
this.info.filter(
  item => Object.values(item.category_data).some(
    cat => this.cat_array.includes(cat))
)
```

*Demo*:

```js
var info = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Title one",
        "category_data": {
            "2": "Team",
            "7": "Queries"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Title two",
        "category_data": {
            "2": "Team",
            "7": "Queries"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Title three",
        "category_data": {
            "2": "Team",
            "7": "Queries"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "Title four",
        "category_data": {
            "2": "Team",
            "7": "Queries"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "title": "Title five",
        "category_data": {
            "2": "Team",
            "6": "Questions",
            "7": "Queries"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "title": "Title six",
        "category_data": {
            "2": "Team",
            "6": "Questions",
            "7": "Queries",
            "12": "Fax",
        }
    }
]

var cat_array = ["Questions"]

console.log(
  info.filter(
    item => Object.values(item.category_data).some(
      cat => cat_array.includes(cat)
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Do you have a codepen for this, the filtering for this is not working as is. Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate further on your answer? Many thanks.

Comment: If you wanted to preserve the text search, I believe what you need is to combine the two criteria with `&&` operator. Btw, I don't see why you have the `All` criteria there, it essentially just means no filter.

Comment: Thanks. I'm very new to Vue and require so hand holding I'm afraid. How would I use the && operator within my existing filter? `   return vm.info.filter(item => {
    return item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.numbers_search_term.toLowerCase()) > -1
        })`

Comment: `this.info.filter(item => Object.values(item.category_data).some(cat => cat_array.includes(cat)) &&  item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.numbers_search_term.toLowerCase()) > -1)` Possibly -

Comment: Thanks, if I amend to this `return this.info.filter(item => Object.values(item.category_data).some(cat => cat_array.includes(cat)) && item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.numbers_search_term.toLowerCase()) > -1)` it returns the filtered. Initially on load, no results appear.